# how to apply if conditional using def with multi parameter

Tags: python, pandas, function, if-statement

I am new to def function , I am trying to get the logic in def function with multiple if condition. I want x,y,z to be flexible parameter so I can change parameter value in x,y,z. but i can't get the desired output. anyone help ?

df =

```
    date      comp  mark    value   score   test1
0   2022-01-01  a      1       10     100   
1   2022-01-02  b      2       20     200   
2   2022-01-03  c      3       30     300   
3   2022-01-04  d      4       40     400   
4   2022-01-05  e      5       50     500
```

Desired ouput =

```
        date    comp    mark    value   score   test1
0   2022-01-01  a          1    10       100    200
1   2022-01-02  b          2    20       200    400
2   2022-01-03  c          3    30       300    600
3   2022-01-04  d          4    40       400    4000
4   2022-01-05  e          5    50       500    5000
```

I can get the result use:

```
    def frml(df):
        if (df['mark'] > 3) and (df['value'] > 30):
            return df['score'] * 10
        else:
            return df['score'] * 2

df['test1'] = df.apply(frml,axis=1)
```

but i can't get the result use this: isn't the logic is the same?

```
 x = df['mark']
 y = df['value']
 z = df['score']

def frml(df):
    if (x > 3) and (y > 30):
        return z * 10
    else:
        return z * 2

df['test1'] = df.apply(frml,axis=1)
```

Comment: No, the logic is not the same.  Within the function, `df` represents a single row of the dataframe, because that's what the `apply` operation gives you.  Outside the function, `df['mark']` refers to an entire COLUMN.  Why can't you use the first format, which is correct?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73669816/19123103) help? Another resource [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73643899/19123103). TL;DR: apply is not good pandas. Use mask or numpy.where instead.

Comment: sorry for late reply, doing some year end thesis.. yes cotton tail thanks for the reference link. it is really helpful.. thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `mask` instead `apply`

```
cond1 = (df['mark'] > 3) & (df['value'] > 30)
df['score'].mul(2).mask(cond1, df['score'].mul(10))
```

output:

```
0     200
1     400
2     600
3    4000
4    5000
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

make output to `test1` column

```
df.assign(test1=df['score'].mul(2).mask(cond1, df['score'].mul(10)))
```

result:

```
    date        comp    mark    value   score   test1
0   2022-01-01  a       1       10      100     200
1   2022-01-02  b       2       20      200     400
2   2022-01-03  c       3       30      300     600
3   2022-01-04  d       4       40      400     4000
4   2022-01-05  e       5       50      500     5000
```

It's possible to explain why your 2nd function doesn't work, but it's complicated.

Also, making your output don't need `apply def func`.

So tell you another way.

use `mask` or `np.where` or `np.select` instead `apply def func`